# How to get value from image

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application where after clicking on an image I want to know where user has clicked.

For example in given [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0ap3C.gif) user clicks on the family room and I want to know about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you cut the image into 5 different images and use 5 imageviews so then whenever a user clicks on one of the image, only the particular image is selected. You will also have the ability to change data differently for different images

Comment: Even better, by using a state list (selector), you can highlight the touched room in a different color.

Answer (score 1):

You can select a part from an image using image cropper like this [image: Sample Screenshot]

For use library code [link](https://github.com/edmodo/cropper)

Comment: I don't want to crop image
like if user click on family room on picture then the server send the value that shows the Family Room is selected 
I don't want to send croped image at server end

Answer (score 0):

You can use different image view. because single imageView can not be splited. so you can use different  ImageView.